# how to use a session for login operation in instagrapi

Tags: python, instagram, instagrapi

I'm almost new to python and i'm writing a bot via instagrapi library.
I wanna use session to avoid logging in every time i run the scrpit.
There was a sample code in documentation of instagrapi, but it didn't work and didn't help. So I need a code to do this..

Thanks.

Tried the code inside the documentation of instagrapi. Didn't work